# Sails generator: Variable targets?

Tags: sails.js

I'm creating a sails generator and I'd like to have my targets choose a template dynamically. I've tried this:

```
targets: {
    './tests/unit/:entityType/:filename': {
        template: scope.entityType + scope.ext,
    }
},
```

However, this throw an error when I try. I'm also unable to use the template variables inside my target object.

Is there a way to do something like this without having to resort to generator composition (calling another generator in my template target)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scope` isn't available when the file with `targets` in it is loaded by `sails-generate` via `require()`, which is why you get an error when trying to refer to it directly.  But you can do what you're looking for by setting a target dynamically in the `before` method of your generator.  So in your `before`, prior to calling the callback, add something like:

```
module.exports.targets["./tests/unit/:entityType/:filename"] = {
    template: scope.entityType + scope.ext,
}
```

Also remember to remove the hard-coded target from your `targets` object--it won't get used but it will probably be confusing!

Comment: Whoa, I didn't realize that you could do this! Although, now that I look at it, it does totally make sense. I'll probably have to pull my `before` function back into index.js instead of having it in its own file, in order to get the right instance of `module.exports`, but I'm sure that this will work. Thanks!

Comment: I think you could keep `before` separate and use `module.parent.exports` if you wanted to get fancy...